# auto event firing when the reminder time is due. can it be done using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, events, reminders

I am storing reminder entities in a mysql database using hibernate.
Now I need to fire an event into the application, whenever the reminder time is due.

How should I go about implementing this, I have looked through hibernate interceptors and event. There are basically triggered on create, save, update or delete, while I need to monitor one of the fields in a table and fire an event when the reminder time is due.

I have also read about configuring cron jobs, but I need the event on time up in the application as a reminder notification has to be shown on the user GUI.

Any suggestion will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Quartz (http://quartz-scheduler.org/). It gives you some possibilities.
One possibility is to schedule the reminder job at the same time when you store the reminder entity.
Alternatively (and possibly more effectively) you could schedule a job that runs periodically and queries the database for the reminder entities that are due until its next run. Then this periodic job will schedule a reminder job for each reminder entity.
Sample code to submit a quartz job:

```
Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
scheduler.start();

JobDataMap map = new JobDataMap();
/* put anything necessary here. */

JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob()
        .withIdentity("MyReminderJobName")
        .withDescription("Reminder Job")
        .usingJobData(map)
        .ofType(MyReminderJob.class)
        .build();       

SimpleScheduleBuilder once = simpleSchedule().repeatSecondlyForTotalCount(1);
Date reminderDate = new Date(); //reminder event date


Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
        .forJob(job)
        .withSchedule(once)
        .startAt()             
        .build();

scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```